# sending online sms with php codes

Tags: php

Compliments.

i am new to php but i have been trying to create an sms platform/notification on my website to compliment the newsletter notification already  created but i am at lost about how to initialize multiple variables to work together as a unit in my php codes. The steps are below:

```
//i favour if...elseif over the switch method 
//to declare the gateways variables

 //step one. declaring gateways variables

$us_ca = array ('@txt.att.net', '@smscellular.com', '@more_gateways');
$nig = array ('@smsairtel.ng.com', '@more_gateways');
$gha = array ('@txt.mtn.com.gh', '@more_gateways');
..................................................

//note that the gateways are not correct but only cited as samples.
// i use more_gateways to represent others i couldn't write
// because of time and space
//step two. where the sms gets delivered.

if zip_code == '+1' {
  email = '$telephone$us_ca', '$zip_code$telephone$us_ca'; //telephone
  var for user's telephone, i create a second because some gateways 
  requires the country zip code.
 } elseif zip_code == '+234'{
  email = '$telephone$nig', '$zip_code$telephone$nig';                  
 } elseif zip_code == '+233'{
  email = '$telephone$gha', '$zip_code$telephone$gha';                  
 }
 ........................................................
 //note that i am targeting almost 90 countries.
```

Now all i want to know is if it's okay to declared the gateways in array var as done above in step one and if initializing multiple var the way i did in the second step isn't bad as well.

Note that each sms is sent to all gateways in an array at the same time since the number each individual phone number is unique to the user that submits it in a given country so the sms can only be delivered to the user alone even though it first gets to all the gateways.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cant send SMS directly from php. You can try twilio or smsgh

Comment: i think i have seen posts online that confirmed that it is possible to send sms through php. do a thorough check online to see for yourself; infact, i got the method through my research but while it is said to be possible to email a gateway (or an array of gateways) at a time, i want to know if i can possibly add up var in that instance. or like below:
      if zip_code == '+1' {
       email = '$zip_code .=$telephone .=$us_ca'
      }
Thanks for your response all the same.

Comment: check this out. https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-send-text-messages-with-php--net-17693

Answer (score 2):

Call sms RestApi in simple PHP function to send sms:

```
function CURLsendsms($number, $message_body){
 $api_params = $api_element.'?apikey='.$apikey.'&sender='.$sender.'&to='.$mobileno.'&message='.$textmessage;
 $smsGatewayUrl = "http://springedge.com";
 $smsgatewaydata = $smsGatewayUrl.$api_params;
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, smsgatewaydata);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 // Use file get contents when CURL is not installed on server.
 if(!$output){
 $output =  file_get_contents($smsgatewaydata);  
 }
}
```

Also you can use php class to send sms 
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9522-PHP-Send-SMS-messages-with-Spring-Edge-API.html

There are two files in above class:

- **sendsms.php** - Class file to call sms gateway restAPI
- **test.php** - Example file to test sms function.

This Class is using spring edge sms gateway provider API you can customize RestAPI url and params for any other sms provider according to requirement.

Comment: thanks for your response but the problem is i don't want to use a paid service for the platform and if i could do without a third party app or website, the better. seems the SMS gateway website you provided is a paid system?

Comment: @test There is no free sms services available as each sms is chargeable for operator. You can go for minimal packages